# Where does Whisper store encryption keys?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-key, whisper

I've noticed that whisper persists symmetric and asymmetric keys created in the geth console by referencing their `id`, but where does it save these keys, and can the directory be configured? Geth's `--datadir` seems like the obvious place where they would be saved, but I've looked and it doesn't seem like they're saved there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Gitter's `@gluk256` for the answer, which I've paraphrased below.

Whisper by default stores the keys in memory and does not allow the user to configure the key storage location. Instead, key storage is left to the dapp to handle.

Comment: I think you should give credit to @Ladek 's answer, since it's the same as yours, and was submitted first.

Comment: @feuGene they copied the Gitter user's answer straight from the chat  and gave no credit to them. My answer gives that original user credit.

Answer (score 0):

It's the dapp layer task. 
The dapp should store the keys and pass them to the whisper layer.

Comment: There's two parts to the question, where the keys are stored and if the directory can be configured.

Comment: Upvoted, but a citation/reference (even to source code) would be nice.